# Hibernate Criteria. Join / Select when no Assosiation

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I am using Hibernate version 4.2

I have 2 Entities.

```
@Entity
public class A {

   Long Id;
  @ManyToOne
   B b;

}

@Entity
public class B {
   Long Id;
   //There is no relation back here with any annotations to A, and can't add a @OneToMany
}
```

is it possible todo a Query with Hibernate Criteria to get a result that looks like this.

**`List<Map<B,List<A>>>`** ? dosn't matter if it is with a join or a select.

example what i want in result:

```
A.id  B.id

1    1,2,3,4
2    
3    5
4    7
5
```

//Trind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got help from Christian Bauer who have Written Hibernate in Action.

Criteria from Hibernate:

```
 List<Object[]> result =
                    session.createCriteria(A.class, "a")
                        .createAlias("b", "i", JoinType.RIGHT_OUTER_JOIN)
                        .setResultTransformer(PassThroughResultTransformer.INSTANCE)
                        .list();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like below. I don't know whether it is your actual requirement though. Assuming B b is OneToOne, 12 is the id of B,

```
Criteria c = session.createCriteria(A.class, "a");
        c.createAlias("a.b", "b"); 
        c.add(Restrictions.eq("a.b.Id", "12"));
        return c.list();
```

this returns a list of arrays and by using those arrays you can form what you want.

Comment: But this way i get it the other way around? if there is a B with no A i wouldn't retrieve the B ? this i will just get All A that has Some B ?

Comment: What is the relation from B to A? OneToOne or ManyToOne?

Comment: There is no relation that way on the entities just on the other way around. i'll clarify it on my question